# CodeIgniter: form submitted with <enter> fails form validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have this problem with CodeIgniter: 
- when I click the submit button in a form, the form is submitted and validated correctly
- when I don't click the submit button, just hit `<enter>`, the form validation always fails
Any solution? Is that a flaw in CI's form validation or am I missing something?

What code I have there:

```
--- the form view ---

form_open("/");
...some inputs...
echo form_submit('submit', 'Přihlásit');
form_close();
...

--- the controller ---

$this->CI->load->helper('form');  
$this->CI->load->library('form_validation');

$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('id_uziv', 'ID', 'required');   
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('heslo', 'Heslo', 'required');  
//... see, no rules have anyhting to do with the submit button

if ($this->CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  // validation OK
}
else {
  // validation failed
}
```

Comment: Roughly what you've got written there works fine for me with an `<enter>` or with a click. You might need to post a small working example (just enough of the controller and the view) that definitely reproduces the problem. As it is, your posted code won't work at all, from what I can see (you're not echoing the results of the form_open() and form_close() so you won't even get the form element output in your HTML...)

Comment: Matt: I made the small working example and it works - that's strange.

Comment: here: http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xmejzl03/f/ci-test-submit.tar.bz2
(these things need to be edited to run it on your server: RewriteBase in .htaccess, $config['base_url'] in system/application/config/config.php)

Answer (score 1):

you're not echoing `form_open('/')`

your form elements will not be enclosed within a `<form>` element so when you submit, no post data will be sent to the server resulting in your validation failing.

Comment: In the real code I am echoing it, it was mistekenly omitted here. I was editing the post to make the code show up as code, not as text. The text editor here is quite horrible in this. Sorry.

Comment: @imploder There's a "code" button in the text editor -- highlight the code and hit it, and everything you've got selected will be formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding an empty validation rule for the submit button, like this:

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('submit_button', 'Submit', '');
```

Now it works. I don't really know what was causing the problem.